# Red separator line not appearing under custom header in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using `viewForHeaderInSection` to implement a header cell.
I've created a separate view, with a height of 1, which I'm assuming should show up as separator.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell") as! CustomHeaderCell

        cell.opt.text = "Some"
        cell.len.text = "LEN"
        cell.wgt.text = "WGT"

        if !cell.constraintsInstalled {
            let constraints = [
                cell.stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.leadingAnchor),
                cell.stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.trailingAnchor),
                cell.stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.topAnchor),
                cell.stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor)
            ]
            cell.contentView.addConstraints(constraints) //vw.addSubview(headerCell)




let separatorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.separatorInset.left, y: cell.frame.height, width: tableView.frame.width - tableView.separatorInset.right, height: 1))
            separatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            cell.addSubview(separatorView)
        }


        return cell

        }
```

Comment: Tip: Use `resuableHeaderFooterView` instead of `cell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should add it to contentView

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(separatorView)
```

Second don't use frames as cell isn't yet laid , you should also use constraints

```
separatorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    separatorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:cell.contentView.leadingAnchor),
    separatorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:cell.contentView.trailingAnchor),
    separatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:1),
    separatorView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:cell.contentView.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Comment: Thank you Sh_Khan. When you say frames, are you referring to : `UIView(frame:)`?
If so what should I be using instead? I found this implementation online so I was trying to get it to work.

Comment: @ShKhan   Instead of frame, I should be using "bounds"? I'm not quite understanding, what I should be using instead. I tried to implement you code but I get` UIView has no member "translateAutoresizing". I changed the cell.Subview to cell.contentView but doesn't seem to be changing anything. Thank you.

Comment: i edited , neither frame or bounds has a correct value , so set it to anything and constraints will overwrite it

Comment: Thank you. I tried running your code, however I'm getting a crash:
`class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate   *Thread1: signal SIGABRT* `

I can't seem to find any other error messages. I will have to run some errands soon, so I won't be able to reply right away. Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting this error:
`anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x1c4675dc0 "UIView:0x105b70dc0.leading"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x1c4675680 "UITableViewCellContentView:0x105b70940.leading"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'"`

Comment: You need to put the constraints after **cell.addSubview(separatorView)** , as a general rule all constraints should be configured after you add the view to it's parent